# Sorceress accepts paper as payment for opening portals to other worlds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the title/author of a fantasy short story. I read it years ago and don't remember a lot of details. A sorceress accepts paper as payment for opening portals to other worlds. I think the person was able to ask 2 or 3 questions about the world before entering. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What is special about accepting paper? Do you mean that she **only** accepts cash money, no credit cards or barter?

Comment: No, not cash/paper money. Writing paper. As I recall, the story was set in a pre-industrial time. Paper, as opposed to gold or gems, was precious to her.